# validating required fields with asp.net required field validators using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <p>
       <label>SOME LABEL</label><span class="required"> *</span>
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="txtBox">
</fieldset>
```

Using jQuery i am trying to get "span.required" and add a class "missing" (changes color to red).

JQuery Code:

```
$('#txtBox').closest('fieldset').find('span.required').addClass('missing');
```

JQUERY CODE FOR required field validator in ASP.NET:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            var val = Page_Validators[i];
            var ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
            if (ctrl != null && ctrl.style != null) {
                if (!val.isvalid) {
                    ctrl.closest('fieldset').find('span.required').addClass('missing');
                }
                else {
                    //alert('no error');

                }
            }
        }
```

ERROR via Console: *object [ctrl object - the textbox]  has no method closest*

i have tried different interations using "find" "parent" etc. but nothing i try seems to work.

What is wrong with my code? I cannot grab that span.required

Thank you to everyone's input, I have learned a lot from each of your input. EVERYONE's answer has valid and working code, however only the selected provided the solution.

Comment: txtbox is the input text box control

Comment: Perhaps it's because you're looking for `span.required-field` where your HTML defines `span.required`?

Comment: sorry i had to clean the code up, keep it short. just wanted to convey the concept.

Comment: Looks fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/68pmR/

Comment: Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: error --> object has no method closest

Comment: @sQuijeW Have you included jQuery in your page?

Comment: @sQuijeW are you sure you call you JS after DOM loaded? Have you looked into my example?

Comment: yes it is there. i am using jquery to tap into the asp required field validator

Comment: Do you have a link we can see?

Comment: @antyrat -- i believe so, all my jquery code is nested insdie document.ready function

Comment: @sQuijeW I don't see any other problems there, my example works fine. and uses your code.

Comment: As you can see by the barrage of comments and answer, what you posted should work. So we'll need more information. Please post the actual code you're using, if possible a jsFiddle.net example, or a link.

Comment: added the jquery for validating fields.

Comment: I just looked at the updated code . . . the reason why `ctrl.closest('fieldset')` wasn't working is because `.closest()` is a JQuery method that acts on an JQuery object, returned by a selector, but `ctrl` is being found using JavaScript and is being set as a DOM node.  You would need to convert the DOM node to a JQuery object first, by doing something like this: `var jqueryCtrl = $(ctrl)`.  Then you would be able to use `jqueryCtrl.closest('fieldset')`.

Comment: if that is the case, would it better to do it that way instead of the method you had proposed (using label and field names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there are a couple of changes in your HTML that you should make which will not only help you solve this issue, but will also make for cleaner, more valid code:

1. Add a `for` attribute to all of your `<label>` tags that pairs them with the input that they match (this really should always be done with labels), and
2. Move the `<span class="required"> *</span>` inside the label (since it really is part of the label)

The resulting code would look like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <p>
        <label for="txtBox">SOME LABEL<span class="required"> *</span></label>
    </p>
    <input type="text" id="txtBox">
</fieldset>
```

Once you've done that, what you are trying to accomplish becomes much easier:

Instead of:

```
ctrl.closest('fieldset').find('span.required').addClass('missing');
```

. . . you can use the id of the input (`val.controltovalidate`) as part of a JQuery selector to find the related label directly:

```
var $targetLabel = $("label[for='" + val.controltovalidate +"']")
$targetLabel.find('span.required').addClass('missing');
```

I've used this many times to pair validations with the labels of the field that is being validated . . . quick and clean.   :)

**Edit:** I split up the last JS piece to keep it from scrolling, but it could be one line.   :)

Comment: Thank you for...
(1) providing a valid solution that goes with what I have done so far
(2) giving me pointers as to how to improve my code
(3) sharing general concepts for best practices

+rep

Comment: question about aesthetics, my html code is nested within a asp content placeholder, so the ID of the actual textbox/control has the ID of the content placeholder concatenated on the front of it.. (eg. txBox --> cph_home_txtBox) cph_home being the ID of the content place holder. why is that? and is there a way to get the ID of the text box without the CPH id? because having the "for=cph_home_txtBox" is long and ugly. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Happy to help.   :)   Unfortunately, I don't use ASP, so I'm not certain about how that works.  Seems like something that you'd be able to change (you should be able to name your fields whatever you want to), but I really don't know.  In the end, though, as long as the meanings of the ids are clear and the format doesn't interfere with another coders ability to read and maintain the code, in my opinion, it's not worth getting too worked up over.   :)

Answer (score 1):

Try txtbox.parent() instead.

`txtbox.parent().find('span.required-field').addClass('missing')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.required').addClass('missing');
```

Comment: Which works fine, so long as there's only one such element on the page. Presumably that is not the case.

Comment: Then OP should reference and ID as there potentially can be many fieldsets and many labels

Comment: im sharing an excerpt of code. if i posted my whole issue it would cause only more confusion. these fieldsets are duplicated many times on the page

Comment: @sQuijeW if it is being used multiple times, which I am assuming in a form for validation, then using classes would be fine.

Comment: @JHuangweb Having an `id` for every element on the page is a really bad idea. The OP's approach is the right one.

Comment: @lonesomeday I was referring that what you mentioned on the first comment. "so long as there's only one such element on the page. Presumably that is not the case."

Comment: @JHuangweb - inputs with labels should always have `id` attributes, because the labels should always have a `for` attribute that matches the `id` attribute of the input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   $('#txtBox').parent().find('span.required').addClass('missing'); 
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/unZPZ/

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out, I used both, closest() and parent().

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            .missing{color:red;}
            .required{color:blue;}
        </style>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function(){
                   $('#txtBox').parent().find("span.required").removeClass("required").addClass("missing"); 
                   //$('#txtBox').closest("fieldset").find("span.required").removeClass("required").addClass("missing"); 
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
               <label>Some Label</label> <span class="required"> *</span>
            </p>
            <input type="text" id="txtBox">
        </fieldset>
    </body>
</html>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/GdBnw/**

HTH.